# How to use react hooks in this code? come three js"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, react-hooks

hello I'm starting with thrrejs on react and found this example on the internet and I would like to know how I can rewrite it using hooks, I tried using useRef (null) but it gave an error, if anyone knows please let me know.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    this.mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( cube );
    camera.position.z = 5;
    var animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame( animate );
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render( scene, camera );
    };
    animate();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} />
    )
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty straightforward refactor. Basically, we can use the `useRef()` hook to create a new ref and pass it down to the  element in the return statement.

Next we replace the componentDidMount function with the `useEffect()` hook. The only thing thats missing here is a return callback to cleanup when the component is unmounted. But since this is a simple example, it's probably not needed here.

```js
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from "three";

function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
    ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    const animate = function () {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    animate();

    return () => {
        // Callback to cleanup three js, cancel animationFrame, etc
    }
  }, []);

  return <div ref={ref} />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but every time I change something in code three, it renders a new canvas, in that old code it doesn't create a new canvas and that's what I want.

Comment: @GustavoEmanuel I would need to see the rest of your code. In the example I gave you, there are no state or props, so there is no reason to re-render the component. If you expect re-rendering, that is what the useEffect cleanup callback is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import * as THREE from "three";



    clet App = () => {
  const mount = useRef(null);

      useEffect(()=>{
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        // document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        // use ref as a mount point of the Three.js scene instead of the document.body
        mount.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );
        camera.position.z = 5;
        var animate = function () {
          requestAnimationFrame( animate );
          cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
          cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
          renderer.render( scene, camera );
        
animate();
},[])
        
      
      render() {
        return (
          <div ref={ref => (mount = ref)} />
        )
      }
    }
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

probably

Comment: it didn't work, mount.appendChild is not a function

Comment: it's late but you just need to add mount.current.appendChild